# Why can I not record ambisonics in Unity with Google Resonance?

Tags: gameaudio, 3d, error, ambisonics

I've set up Unity (2018.4.0f1 LTS) with the [Google Resonance](https://resonance-audio.github.io/resonance-audio/develop/unity/developer-guide) project and I'm attempting to record an ambisonic environment with the Resonance Audio Listener component - however on hitting Record, instead, I get the following error,

Failed to start soundfield recording.
 UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
 ResonanceAudioListener:StartSoundfieldRecorder() (at Assets/ResonanceAudio/Scripts/ResonanceAudioListener.cs:121)
 ResonanceAudioListenerEditor:OnInspectorGUI() (at Assets/ResonanceAudio/Editor/ResonanceAudioListenerEditor.cs:108)
 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)

I've spent some time poking through the included scripts and as far as I can see the problem is located in one of the included .dlls, so I don't think I can diagnose it myself.

Kinda desperate for a solution, here, folks, as I have a very close deadline that depends on making an ambisonic recording of the experience I've built.

I should mention that I'm not much of a sound guy, I'm just trying to facilitate the sound guy on our team... =D

Answer (score 1):

Recording Ambisonic A-Format audio is a fairly specialised task which should be undertaken by someone with experience in that particular field.

You need a 4-channel field recorder with *identical* gain and phase structures across all 4 channels in order to record the 4-channel 1st order A Format signal. There are not many recording devices that are suitable for this.

I would not recommend trying to record this directly into a computer as the audio interface that is likely going to end up being used will not have the gain-structure linking required for this to be effective.

Devices like the SD-788, SD-644, SD-688, Zoom F8n, Zoom F4n, SD-Mixpre, Zoom-F6 are all suitable.

Once the A-Format signal has been acquired it will need to be converted to B-Format Ambix or Fuma format. This is performed using a processing tool that is *specific* for each ambisonic mic. Once you have it in B-Format, you can start applying it inside of Unity. Processing is normally performed inside a DAW.